# How to keep colors of previous lines in Rebol/Red

Tags: colors, draw, rebol, red

I am trying to draw lines of different colors in modified paint program:

```
REBOL [title: "Paint"]
mycol: black
view layout [ size 1100x700
    s: area 1060x600 white feel [
        engage: func [f a e] [
            if a = 'over [append s/effect/draw e/offset  show s]
            if a = 'up [append s/effect/draw 'line]
        ]
    ] effect [draw [pen mycol line]]
    across
    btn "Clear" 100x50 [s/effect/draw: copy [line] show s]
    btn "Red" 100x50 [set [to-word mycol] red]
    btn "blue" 100x50 [set [to-word mycol] blue]
    btn "magenta" 100x50 [set [to-word mycol] magenta]
    btn "green" 100x50 [set [to-word mycol] green]
    btn "yellow" 100x50 [set [to-word mycol] yellow]
    btn "orange" 100x50 [set [to-word mycol] orange]
    btn "Quit" 100x50 [quit]
]
```

However, when I select a color, all lines in area change color. How can I modify so that earlier lines remain of same color?

Comment: Is this rebol2? (talking about the tag)

Comment: REBOL/view 2.7.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example looks like this

```
view layout [
    s: area white feel [
        engage: func [f a e] [
            if a = 'over [append s/effect/draw e/offset  show s]
            if a = 'up [append s/effect/draw 'line]
        ]
    ] effect [draw [pen blue line]]
    btn "Clear" [s/effect/draw: copy [line] show s]
    btn "Red" [append s/effect/draw [pen red line]]
]
```

So your script should be

```
view layout [ size 1100x700
    s: area 1060x600 white feel [
        engage: func [f a e] [
            if a = 'over [append s/effect/draw e/offset  show s]
            if a = 'up [append s/effect/draw 'line]
        ]
    ] effect [draw [pen black line]]
    across
    btn "Clear" 100x50 [s/effect/draw: copy [line] show s]
    btn "Red" 100x50 [append s/effect/draw [pen red line]]
    btn "blue" 100x50 [append s/effect/draw [pen blue line]]
    btn "magenta" 100x50 [append s/effect/draw [pen magenta line]]
    btn "green" 100x50 [append s/effect/draw [pen gree line]]
    btn "yellow" 100x50 [append s/effect/draw [pen yellow line]]
    btn "orange" 100x50 [append s/effect/draw [pen orange line]]
    btn "Quit" 100x50 [quit]
]
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain about `engage` and `effect`. Also, a button to add text is not working. I am trying code: `btn "text" [append s/effect/draw ['text 100x100 "Graphics Plot" ]]` . (I cannot ask new questions for some time now!).

Comment: @rnso Documentation on [Face Effect](http://www.rebol.com/docs/view-face-effects.html), [Draw](http://www.rebol.com/docs/draw.html) dialect (is somewhat compatible with SVG), and [Event Handling](http://www.rebol.com/docs/view-face-events.html) (`engage`).

Answer (score 4):

The [Draw dialect](http://www.rebol.com/docs/draw.html) is a cumulative description of a drawing. In your example, you only set the pen colour once and all lines thereafter inherit said colour. As you set the pen colour using the word `mycol`, all your lines are set to whatever colour that word refers to once the face display is updated (`show s` in your code above).

Can break things down a little here to understand some of the operations:

### The Drawing

Let's initiate the drawing in it's own object with the current colour.

```
drawing: make object! [
    image: []
    color: black
    use: func [new [tuple!]][
        append image reduce ['pen color: new]
    ]
    reset: does [
        clear image
        use color
    ]
    reset
]
```

Here we have everything we need to manage the settings of the drawing:

**image** — the drawing itself (in the Draw dialect).

**color** — the current pen colour.

**use** — a function to change the current color and apply it to the drawing.

**reset** — clears the drawing.

### The Canvas

Our canvas will be a simple BOX face which will contain the drawing:

```
box 1060x600 white
effect reduce ['draw drawing/image]
```

And will react to `down` and `over` actions passed via the [Engage](http://www.rebol.com/docs/view-face-events.html#section-11) function:

```
feel [
    engage: func [face action event] [
        switch action [
            down [append drawing/image 'line]
            over [append drawing/image event/offset show face]
        ]
    ]
]
```

*(I've changed the engage parameters here to their full names—there's little efficiency gained and much expressivity lost in Rebol/Red using one-letter words)*

This should work as per the engage function in your example except that new lines are started on a `down` action.

### Actions

Our 'Clear' button engages the `drawing` object and resets the canvas (the button's oldest sibling):

```
btn "Clear" 100x50 [
    drawing/reset
    show first face/parent-face/pane
]
```

Just for a little interface sugar, we'll use toggles to indicate the current colour. You can create a mutual relationship between toggles using the `of` keyword:

```
tog of 'color "Red"     100x50 [drawing/use red]
tog of 'color "Blue"    100x50 [drawing/use blue]
tog of 'color "Magenta" 100x50 [drawing/use magenta]
tog of 'color "Green"   100x50 [drawing/use green]
tog of 'color "Yellow"  100x50 [drawing/use yellow]
tog of 'color "Orange"  100x50 [drawing/use orange]
```

## Bringing It Together

Can wrap this up in a script:

```
Rebol [Title: "Paint"]

drawing: make object! [
    image: []
    color: black
    use: func [new [tuple!]][
        append image reduce ['pen color: new]
    ]
    reset: does [
        clear image
        use color
    ]
    reset
]

view layout [
    box 1060x600 white
    effect reduce ['draw drawing/image]
    feel [
        engage: func [face action event] [
            switch action [
                down [append drawing/image 'line]
                over [append drawing/image event/offset show face]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    across
    btn "Clear" 100x50 [drawing/reset show face/parent-face/pane/1]
    tog of 'color "Red"     100x50 [drawing/use red]
    tog of 'color "Blue"    100x50 [drawing/use blue]
    tog of 'color "Magenta" 100x50 [drawing/use magenta]
    tog of 'color "Green"   100x50 [drawing/use green]
    tog of 'color "Yellow"  100x50 [drawing/use yellow]
    tog of 'color "Orange"  100x50 [drawing/use orange]
    btn "Quit" 100x50 [unview]
]
```